# NHibernate 3.3 partial sql logs

Tags: sql, nhibernate, logging

I am using NHibernate 3.3 in a project of mine, and I have a series of tests that I am developing as I go.  I have the logging setup in the main configuration so as I run my tests the generated queries are logged to STD out, etc.

Everything is working just fine, except for the fact that NH seems to only be logging SELECT statements.  I have many cases where there are known update and delete operations, but only the SELECTs actually appear in the log.

To reiterate, in my configuration I have set:

```
  db.LogSqlInConsole = true;
  db.LogFormattedSql = true;
```

But only SELECT statements appear in the log?  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there are updates/inserts being ran? What dbms are you using?  If you are using ms sql run profiler to see if there are additional queries that are being ran that aren't captured.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the update is being run (the data gets updated!!)  If I wasn't sure, I wouldn't ask the question.  I wish I could downvote your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DML statements are not logged to the console.

Answer (score -1):

Last time I tried, DML statements were not logged to the console when batching (which is on by default for supported dialects)

Comment: DML ?? I'm bad with acronyms, what is that?

Comment: Isn't that nice... my mistake for wasting my time with you. It won't happen again, I promise.

Comment: Unlike you, I can Google **and** get sarcasm.